# Launch some application using Dragon Dictate on mac

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, speech-recognition

I'd like to use Dragon Dictate to automate launching of some app(for example Terminal). To be more accurate, I need a list of instructions eg:

1) Open Spotlight
2) Search for an app
3) Focus it
4) Launch the app

And info of how to configure OS and DD.
I'm going to start reading docs right now, and maybe I'll find an answer.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, perhaps it would be better suited if asked on [su]?  Also, why not read docs ***before*** you ask a question?

Comment: It was easy, you can just add voice command like "Terminal", and assign application to this command. But now I'd like to make a command with parameter, to tell 'launch #{app-name}' instead one command for every app.

And sometimes you can get the answer from asking a question much faster than from reading doc.

I keep reading docs)

Comment: maybe keep reading the docs?